# In magento 2 , while uploading a image ,where the image will be saved temporarily

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, image-upload, image-preview

I have created UI-component form.In that, I have more than 1 image fields while uploading an image where I need to check whether the image is saved in a temporary directory or not?
Noe the image is saved in temporary directory as well as pub/media folder.
**Now I need to create new folder to save my small, large, medium,extra large in seperate folders inside my module folder. Please provide me a solution**

**upload.php(upload controller)**

```
public function execute()
    {
        try {
            //Saves the image in temporary directory
            // $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('general[image]');

            if (isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']['small_image'])) {
                //$this->checkImage('upload', $this->helperData->getSmallImageProperties(), 'small_image');
                $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('upload[small_image]');
            } 
            else if (isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']['medium_image'])) {
               // $mediumImage = $this->checkImage('upload', $this->helperData->getMediumImageProperties(), 'medium_image');
                $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('upload[medium_image]');
            } 

            elseif (isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']['large_image'])) {
               // $this->checkImage('upload', $this->helperData->getLargeImageProperties(), 'large_image');
                $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('upload[large_image]');
            }
            elseif (isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']['extra_large_image'])) {
                //$this->checkImage('upload', $this->helperData->getExtraLargeImageProperties(), 'extra_large_image');
                $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('upload[extra_large_image]');
            }

}
```

Comment: It will be in present in Pub/media/your_folder

Comment: Now My images are saved in Pub/ media folder. But I need to save my images in specific folder(myfolder) inside pub/media.

Comment: You need to Specify the path for image after being saved in your code..

Comment: Refer this site                                                         
                                                                                 
               https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-upload-image-in-magento2/

Comment: I need to save in pub/media. But I need to save pub/media/Newfolder. So Where I need to created NewFolder via programatically.

Comment: You need to write code in controller , you need to create folder first. So that it will be saved in that folder path.

Comment: Then While uploading  which means in upload controller right

Comment: Yes Obviously...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72497/discussion-between-sri-and-aravind).

Comment: @aravind I have updated the post.the above upload controller works good but, the images are saved in pub/media folder. Now how do I update my code to save in a new folder

Comment: You can save it to custom folder , Just try if not i will look for alternate solution                                                   
                                                                                                                            
$result = $this -> imageUploader                                                                             
->saveFileToTmpDir('myfolder/'.'upload[small_image]');

Comment: No, It shows undefined index error